The smallest possible area of an convex lattice polygon
Given a number $n\geq3\in \mathbb{N}$,let $f(n)$ be the least possible area of an convex lattice n-gon,find the expression of $f(n)$ for any $n$.
So I've got $f(3)=0.5,f(4)=1$ trivally,$f(5)=2.5,f(6)=3,f(7)\leq6.5,f(8)=7,f(9)\leq10.5,f(10)\leq14,$

How did you arrive at these numbers?

@uniquesolution,Hmm I think it's just try to find a polygon that fits your intuition best.

Pick's Theorem is useful.

@MathFont yes Pick's Theorem is literally how I constructed these values

See https://oeis.org/A070911

@lhf thx,that's helpful.

The asymptotics of $f$ are known, see The Minimum Area of Convex Lattice n-Gons by Bárány, Tokushige.
